# c++ : An array of the pointer float type with dynamic size

Tags: c++, pointers

**Is this Correct?**

Will **stereoBuffer**  be an array of the pointer float type with size mixQty (i.e. 2);

```
// C++ in Header File

float **stereoBuffer;

// in cpp file inside a function of init

mixQty = 2; // this will be passed in function

stereoBuffer = new float*[mixQty];

for (int i = 0; i < mixQty; ++i) {
    stereoBuffer[i] = (float *)malloc(samplerate * 2 * sizeof(float) + 32768);
}
```

Help and Detail answer will be rewarded.

Comment: Is it C or C++? In C++ you should avoid using `malloc` (and `new` in modern C++).

Comment: Why mixing `new` (C++) and `malloc` (C) ?

Comment: prefer `std::vector<std::vector<float>>` over `float**` in C++.

Comment: Its C++, basically in Android using C++ with JNI to do some Audio Processing.
I am confused regarding Dynamic allocation of pointer array.

Its not Malloc and New than what should be used ?

Comment: @NathanOliver i am using an library which accepts **float.
will std::vector<std::vector<float>> still work if i'll pass for function accepting **float.

Thank You

Comment: @KathanShah `malloc` is used in C and supported in C++ mostly for compatibility. `new` was used in C++ as an alternative until smart pointers were introduced. Now, `std::make_unique` and `std::make_shared` are preferred for dynamic allocation. Though in this case, just using an `std::vector` will do and there is no reason to manually allocate memory.

Comment: Something that makes both `vector<float>` and `new float[...]` problematic in this case is the extra 32768 bytes added to the end of the allocation. Unless that can be changed I don't see any alternative to `malloc` or `new char[...]`

Comment: @john That's not really a big deal.  `std::vector<float>(samplerate * 2 + 8192)` is the same thing as long as you assert `sizeof(float) == 4`.

Comment: @KathanShah You can, you'll just have to store a pointer to all of the sub vectors in a `vector<float*>` and then pass the `data` of that vector to the function.

Comment: @NathanOliver Well, I'm not sure I agree with that. For one thing it gives the impression that you really do have a vector of floats instead of the more complex object that the OP has. Also you are going to default construct a lot of floats which isn't necessary. Finally why assume anything at all. If the reality is that this is not a vector of floats then why pretend it is.

Comment: @john well, OP's code is allocating `(float *)[]` I don't see where this can be interpreted as not `float`.

Comment: @KathanShah I think you would first get multi define error for `stereoBuffer` before any allocating problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this Correct?

*No*. Mixing `new` and `malloc()` is not a good idea.

If you must use dynamic memory allocation, then read this: [How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new)

Otherwise, use an [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).

Comment: The posted code is correct, not a good idea does not mean incorrect.

Comment: I am talking about the concept @john

Comment: There's also the fact that the code above adds an extra 32768 bytes to the end of each 'row'. `std::vector<float>` or `new float[]` are going to have trouble with that.

Comment: @john
float **stereoBuffer;

in Loop
stereoBuffer[i] = (float *)malloc(samplerate * 2 * sizeof(float) + 32768);

how can i do "(float *)malloc(samplerate * 2 * sizeof(float) + 32768);" with new

Comment: @KathanShah Since you seem to be allocating a mixture of floats and bytes, I think you have to use new char[]. `stereoBuffer[i] = (float *)new char[samplerate * 2 * sizeof(float) + 32768];` but this is not very different from using malloc, so maybe in this unusual case malloc is OK.

Comment: @john Your suggestion violates strict aliasing and the object model.  You have a pointer to `char`, not `float`.  there aren't actually any `float`s in that storage so you can't legally use it as an array of `float`s.

Comment: @NathanOliver: That's a needlessly g++-specific view of things. Never understood why it strives to be an impractical compiler. Goodness.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It's what the standard mandates: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/intro.object#1

Comment: @NathanOliver It's not me that violating anything, it seems to be the API that the OP is working with.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Consider how you get from bytes allocated to array of `floats`. The compiler specific is to have to use placement `new`. That's the wholly impractical g++ formalistic no-op stuff. Never understood why it imposes such impractical silliness. It's almost like it attempts to "teach" programmers to follow every letter of the standard, no matter what.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf c++ developpers *are* to follow every letter of the standard, no matter what. Otherwise, they aren't programming in c++.

Comment: That was never the intention with the language. It was intended as a practical programmer's language, not a language to do formalistic please-the-g++-compiler stuff in. It was intended as practical, as all the stuff originating from Bell Labs.

Answer (score 1):

> Will stereoBuffer be an array of the pointer float type

It will be (a pointer to the first element of) an array of type pointer-to-float.

Each element of this array will be a pointer to the first element of an array of float.

As gsamaras notes, mixing `new` and `malloc` like this is terrible practice. It's needlessly hard to correctly deallocate and there's no error checking. You could at least use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<float[]>>` and let it take care of deallocation correctly for you.

```
using StereoBuffer = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<float[]>>;

StereoBuffer allocateStereoBuffer(size_t mixQty, size_t samplerate)
{
  StereoBuffer buf(mixQty);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < mixQty; ++i) {
    buf[i] = make_unique<float[]>(samplerate * 2 * 32768); // ?
  }
  return buf;
}
```